# Unawarded but ended bounty prevents closure

Tags: support, vote-to-close, bounty, grace-period

There's a question that is a duplicate of an older one with fitting answers. However, the question had a bounty so I couldn't close it - that's expected, so I decided to wait until it was awarded or expired.

The current answers don't solve the problem, so none has been accepted and the bounty ran an entire week. After that I tried to close it, but it appears the grace period was still active. OK, so I waited another day. Now both bounty and grace period have expired, and the post has a notice

> This question had a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) worth <kbd>+50</kbd> reputation from […] that ended **yesterday**.
>   Grace period has ended

<sub>(Btw, that second sentence seems to miss a full stop)</sub>

So I've tried to close it now, but I'm still receiving the error

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed

What's going on? How is an ended bounty still open? Do I need to wait for some mechanism to remove the bounty (like the auto-awarding script, which seems to lag behind a bit sometimes)? Or is this a bug and I need a moderator to close it?

Comment: Link? Wouldn't mind trying to reproduce it.

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought to avoid the meta effect by not sharing it, but [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38939570/1048572) (close by the link I gave in the comments there).

Comment: I tried to close it. Getting same message.

Comment: Same message in the app (same api, naturally)

Comment: I just found this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235330/bug-in-time-of-expiring-bounty, which would explain what' s going on.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Seen that as well, but it's about notifications. Maybe it explains the delay of Community, but still, the close vote should check the actual expiry date not wait for some scheduled event.

Comment: Good point on the date check. Maybe the system is related, maybe not...

Answer (score 2):

The bounty seem to have ended just a moment ago. I was able to close it as duplicate:

> [image] <sub>([source](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38939570/timeline))</sub>

I'm guessing there's some timezone shenanigans going on with the bounty expiration date / time, as there's no other mention of a bounty in the timeline, aside from the bounty's start.

Comment: Looks like I've been too impatient. It worked for me now as well after the bounty was really removed. Given the bounty was started at 6:08, but the Community user didn't act before 8:07, there was a very confusing message on the question for about two hours.

Comment: That's timezone shenanigans. Those 2 hours smell of a 1-hour offset + daylight savings time. (UTC+2)

Comment: No, both times are in UTC, there shouldn't been an issue with that. Or does the community really live in Europe?

Comment: Could be that the bounty was started from a +2 client, and the community user ignores the timezone (Or the timezone isn't taken into consideration when starting bounties?) We may need someone to verify this in the back-end...